# High CPU Usage - Android Emulator (qemu-system-x86)

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator, cpu-usage, qemu

Distro - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64
System Specs -
RAM: 8G
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon V
GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Picasso
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile

Running only android studio works just fine but when i try to just open my firefox it becomes too much for the system and it makes the whole system slow like can't even open my terminal. I have to press and hold my power button to shutdown and reboot.

By using top - %CPU even shown 600.3 which is insane!!!

Comment: Something seems to be off with the latest release. Checking adb shell I can see high bluetooth cpu usage